# zlib.gunzipSync is not in node.js used in meteorhacks:npm

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, zlib

I use meteorhacks:npm to import npm module Telegram.link in meteor. It works fine but when I call a specific function, I see this Error:

```
W20160218-16:37:38.369(3.5)? (STDERR) /home/omid/Documents/test3/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/telegram.link/node_modules/telegram-mt-node/lib/net/encrypted-rpc-channel.js:75
W20160218-16:37:38.370(3.5)? (STDERR)         var buffer = zlib.gunzipSync(packedData);
W20160218-16:37:38.370(3.5)? (STDERR)                           ^
W20160218-16:37:38.377(3.5)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'gunzipSync'
W20160218-16:37:38.377(3.5)? (STDERR)     at checkIfGzipped (/home/omid/Documents/test3/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/telegram.link/node_modules/telegram-mt-node/lib/net/encrypted-rpc-channel.js:75:27)
W20160218-16:37:38.377(3.5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._onTimeout (/home/omid/Documents/test3/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/telegram.link/node_modules/telegram-mt-node/lib/net/encrypted-rpc-channel.js:67:28)
W20160218-16:37:38.377(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
```

I Think the problem is about version of NodeJs used in meteorhacks:npm(v0.10.* according to .node_version file) and in that version there is no **gunzipSync** . I looked at v5.6.0 and there was a gunzipSync in that.
I changed version in file .node_version to v5.6.* and nothing changed.
the code that throws exception is:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
function checkIfGzipped(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'boolean' && obj.instanceOf('mtproto.type.Gzip_packed')) {
        var packedData = obj.packed_data;
        logger.info("Gzip packed data [%s]", packedData ? packedData.toString('hex') : null);
        var buffer = zlib.gunzipSync(packedData);
        logger.info("Buffer after gunzip [%s]", buffer.toString('hex'));
        var Type = tl.TypeBuilder.requireTypeFromBuffer(buffer);
        return new Type({buffer: buffer}).deserialize();
    }
    else return obj;
}
```

Is there any way to inject functionality of gunzipSync function so that checkIfGzipped function start working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem!
I  found a [code](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/raw/master/bin/node-zlib.js) that does the zlib works and I changed the telegram.link package in order to use this one instead of nodejs built-in one:

```
var zlib = require('./node-zlib.js');
```